# Multi Threading in php with Drupal 7

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I am using framework Drupal 7 and environment Windows with mysql. I have a question that I want Asynchronus call in php where I have to update certain values in database but I don't want to stop the execution of a function. Function should complete and return value even if the database processing is going one.

I was thinking of threads approach where one thread is working to update on database and other thread will complete and return function. Is it possible in php ?? If yes then how ??

Comment: Take a look at the drupal batch api

Answer (score 0):

There are a thousand questions about PHP multithreading as of now and they all "work" on Drupal. Multithreading isn't really supported in PHP. My bet is that you need to use this function.

```
passthru("/usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php ".$argv_parameter." >> /path/to/log_file.log 2>&1 &");
```

That will make it stay running in the background and output the results to your log.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Process component from Symfony2 framework:
http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/process.html

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the HTTP Parallel Request & Threading Library module: https://www.drupal.org/project/httprl

I think the function you would want is httprl_queue_background_callback() and then httprl_send_request(). See the examples (the API documentation is not so great).

Answer (score -1):

Here's a link to a multi threading Drush tutorial I wrote which might help you with multi threading examples in Drupal 7:

http://deeson-online.co.uk/labs/multi-threading-part-1-how-make-drush-rush

Comment: While a link may answer the question, you should post atleast a summary of the solution here as the link may not always exist.

Comment: ... and the link is dead. I wish John would have followed Smern recommendation.